# A better way to parse text input in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've been trying Advent of Code challenges to learn Clojure. I've successfully completed Day 2, but I feel like my solution is very clumsy, especially the functions for parsing text input.

**Instructions:**

Imagine there is a sequence of games played, encoded in a text file, one game per line. Each game consists of an id and a sequence of (semicolon-delimited) draws of colored cubes from a small bag. Each draw is encoded as a (comma-delimited) sequence of numbers of cubes drawn per color.

Example line (game):
`Game 2: 1 green, 1 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue; 1 blue, 18 red; 9 red, 1 green; 2 blue, 11 red, 1 green; 1 green, 2 blue, 10 red`

The goal is to parse such file for further processing.

**My solution:**

```clj
(defn parse-coloring [coloring]
  (let [tokens (clojure.string/split coloring #" ")
        color (second tokens)
        value (Integer/parseInt (first tokens))]
    { :color color :value value }))

(defn parse-draw [draw]
  (let [colorings (clojure.string/split draw #", ")]
    (map parse-coloring colorings)))

(defn parse-line [line]
  (let [matches (re-matches #"^Game (\d+): (.*)$" line)
        game-id (Integer/parseInt (nth matches 1))
        game (nth matches 2)
        draws (clojure.string/split game #"; ")]
    { :id game-id :draws (map parse-draw draws)}))

(def games
  (let [input (slurp "C:\\Users\\...\\input.txt")
        lines (clojure.string/split-lines input)]
    (map parse-line lines)))
```

I'm looking for a more simple, succinct, idiomatic-clojure solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've nailed it pretty well.  The only thing I would do is replace `map` with `mapv` everywhere (simpler to avoid lazy lists).  Also, as a big believer in TDD, I've added how I would throw in some unit tests to include "live" documentation of what/how each fn works.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as str]))
```

I start off using my [favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) and library.

```
(defn parse-coloring [coloring]
  (let [tokens (clojure.string/split coloring #" ")
        color  (second tokens)
        value  (Integer/parseInt (first tokens))]
    {:color color :value value}))

(verify
  (is= (parse-coloring "1 green")
    {:color "green" :value 1}))
```

So we see the pattern of a unit test for each small function, so a new reader sees sample input/output.

```
(defn parse-draw [draw]
  (let [colorings (clojure.string/split draw #", ")]
    (map parse-coloring colorings)))

(verify
  (is= (parse-draw "1 green, 1 blue, 1 red")
    [{:color "green" :value 1}
     {:color "blue" :value 1}
     {:color "red" :value 1}]))
```

Same for this function...

```
(defn parse-game [line]
  (let [matches (re-matches #"^Game (\d+): (.*)$" line)
        game-id (Integer/parseInt (nth matches 1))
        game    (nth matches 2)
        draws   (clojure.string/split game #"; ")]
    {:id game-id :draws (map parse-draw draws)}))

(verify
  (is= (parse-game "Game 1: 1 green, 1 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue")
    {:id    1
     :draws [[{:color "green" :value 1}
              {:color "blue" :value 1}
              {:color "red" :value 1}]
             [{:color "red" :value 11}
              {:color "blue" :value 3}]]}))
```

and this one.  We're almost done.

```
(defn separate-games
  [text]
  (mapv str/trim (str/split-lines (str/trim text))))

(defn parse-input
  [text]
  (let [game-strs    (separate-games text)
        games-parsed (mapv parse-game game-strs)]
    games-parsed))
```

I broke this up into 2 functions to make unit testing easier.

```
(verify
  (let [; throw in some gratuitous leading/trailing newlines to check robustness
        input         "

            Game 1: 1 green, 1 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue
            Game 2: 9 green, 9 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue; 1 blue, 18 red

    "
        game-strs     (separate-games input)
        strs-expected ["Game 1: 1 green, 1 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue"
                       "Game 2: 9 green, 9 blue, 1 red; 11 red, 3 blue; 1 blue, 18 red"]]
    (is= game-strs strs-expected)
```

So we can verify the line-by-line parsing independently of the other processing.

Now, we verify the whole kit-n-kaboodle for a 2 line file.

```
    (let [games-parsed (parse-input input)]
      (is= games-parsed
        [{:draws
          [[{:color "green", :value 1}
            {:color "blue", :value 1}
            {:color "red", :value 1}]
           [{:color "red", :value 11} {:color "blue", :value 3}]],
          :id 1}
         {:draws
          [[{:color "green", :value 9}
            {:color "blue", :value 9}
            {:color "red", :value 1}]
           [{:color "red", :value 11} {:color "blue", :value 3}]
           [{:color "blue", :value 1} {:color "red", :value 18}]],
          :id 2}]))))
```